# With Liferay7, Can I change existed portal filter behavior, like AutoLoginFilter

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

After I opened Auto Login function for my portal, it worked very well. That I visited any page will cause an autologin trigger.

```
auto.login.hooks=acn.autologin.login.MyAutoLogin
```

But I hope "Auto Login" will be triggered only when I visited specified url. When I visited other urls, I will still login with a normal login page.
Is it possible to change url pattern of Auto Login filter?

I have done this kind of thing in liferay 6.2 by update servlet-filter definition in hook xml file. But liferay 7 seems not suggest to use this way to define filter and update exited filter. Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/auto-login
should give you the info about registering your autologins as a DS component

the filter hook is described in here
http://www.javasavvy.com/liferay-dxp-filter-tutorial/

remember everything is now hidden in @component Annotations

is it that what your searching for ?